# ssh & curl command with remote server

Tags: curl, ssh, server

I have question about remote server and curl message.

For now I send command on my server to torchserve like this:

```
ssh user@192.168.0.5
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/predictions/densenet161 -T kitten.jpg
```

But my question is if I'm not on my server and I should I send the same curl command and get the result .

```
home -> server -> send curl message
```

Is it possible to:

```
ssh user@192.168.0.5
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/predictions/densenet161 -T kitten.jpg
```

in one line?

```
ssh user@ipaddress -p 5902 curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/predictions/densenet161 -T kitten.jpg
```

Comment: Your "one line" command looks like it ought to work. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

`sh` or `bash` can be used with a complex command.
As well as single `'` or double `"` quotes.

```bash
URL=http://127.0.0.1:8080/predictions/densenet161
FILE=kitten.jpg
ssh user@ipaddress -p 5902 "sh -c 'curl -X POST $URL -T $FILE'"
```

Answer (score -1):

why do you need to ssh into that server?
you could just directly curl to that server by

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.0.5:8080/predictions/densenet161 -T kitten.jpg
```

Comment: assuming you have kitten.jpg in your host from where you are making the curl request